# What does it mean when the test scores are more than 100?

Tags: python, neural-network, mlp

The MLP I created when tested on test sets shows a test score more than 100 multiple times. Could there be any mistake in coding or the data entered?

My code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim = 6))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=opt , loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(x, y, epochs=ep, batch_size = 50 ,verbose=0)
test_score = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose = 0)
test_score = sqrt(test_score)
test_score = get_unscaled (test_sf, np.array([test_score]))
```

Comment: Why should the score not be higher than 100?

Comment: @mkrieger1 So its not like 100 is the maximum value.. The most accurate?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe the maximum value is 500? Or there is no maximum value?

Comment: @mkrieger1 You see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46800337/14594061) According to this answer, The maximum value has to be hundred, right?

Answer (score -1):

`model.evaluate` can return two types of values:

- Scalar: If you have not explicitly passed a value to the `metric` attribute to `model.compile`, it returns only the loss (which if it is mean squared error can be any non-negative real).
- List of scalars: If you have passed metrics to `model.compile`, `model.evaluate` returns a list of scalars, the first element is the loss and all others are values of the metrics you passed.

To solve your question simply, pass your desired metric (say accuracy) to `model.compile` like `model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])`. Running `model.evaluate` will then return `[loss, accuracy]`. Refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile).

You need to understand what you're doing before you start coding. It seems you are unclear on the meaning of mean squared error. Please do some reading up, both the theory and the Keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate), first.

Comment: Sorry! I am a beginner. Just clarifying that the error here was that the test scores were not calculated right. I used loss instead of accuracy to calculate them. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no constraint on the loss function you've used to be upper bounded by 100.